# I'm looking for a good psuedo random number generator, that takes two inputs instead of one

Tags: algorithm, random

I'm looking for a determenistic psuedo random generator that takes two inputs and always returns the same output.  I'm looking for things like uniform distribution, unpredictable as possible, and doesn't repeat for a long long time.  Ideally the function doesn't rely on previous values.  The reason that is a problem is I'm generating terrain data for an extremely large procedurely generated world and can't afford to store previous values.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

i think what you're looking for is [perlin noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise) - it's a way of generating "random" values in 2d (typically) that look like terrain / clouds / etc.

note that this doesn't have much to do with cryptography etc, but a "real" random number source is probably not what you want for synthetic terrain (it looks too noisy/spikey).

there's a [good article on perlin noise here](http://devmag.org.za/2009/04/25/perlin-noise/).

the implementation of perlin noise does use a source of random numbers, but typically you can use whatever is present on your system (starting with a known seed if you want to reproduce it later).

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem deciding on a PRNG algorithm to use or an algorithm that accepts 2 inputs?

If it's the former, why not use the built in random class - such as `Random` class in .NET - since it strives for uniform distribution and long cycles. Also, given the same seed it will generate the same sequence of numbers.

If it's the latter, what you can do is map the 2 inputs to a single ouput and use that as a seed to your random algorithm. You can define a simple hash function that takes a string and calculates an integer from it:

```
s[0] + s[1]^1 + s[2]^2 + ... s[n]^n = seed
```

Answer (score 0):

Combination of two inputs (by concatenating each other, provided the inputs are binary integers) into one seed will do, for a PRNG, such as Mersenne Twister.